# Why am i receiving a KeyError when interacting with the second window that appears with PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

The user can search for names in the database with the search box and select the name they want. a second window will appear for them to enter information.
Any interaction with the second window causes a KeyError for values["IN"].

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

pt_list = ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"]

def make_window1():
    layout = [
        [sg.Button("Add New Patient", key = "ADD"), sg.Button("Remove Patient", key = "RMV")],
        [sg.Input("Search patient name", key = "IN", enable_events = True), sg.Button("Search", key = "SEARCH")],
        [sg.Listbox(pt_list, expand_x = True, expand_y = True, key = "LIST", enable_events = True)]
        ]

    return sg.Window("WINDOW1", layout, finalize = True)

def make_window2():
    layout = [
        [sg.Text("A second window has appeared.")],
        [sg.Button("Close 2nd window")],
        ]

    return sg.Window("WINDOW2", layout, finalize = True)

def main():
    window2 = None
    window1 = make_window1()

    while True:
        window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED and window == window1 or event == "Quit":
            break

        #Patient selcetion list
        # if a keystroke entered in search field
        if values['IN'] != '':                         
            search = values['IN']
            # do the filtering
            new_values = [x for x in pt_list if search in x]
            # display in the listbox
            window['LIST'].update(new_values)     
        else:
        # display original unfiltered list
            window['LIST'].update(pt_list)
        # if a list item is chosen, switch to patient folder
        if event == 'LIST' and len(values['LIST']):
            window2 = make_window2()
            window1.hide()

        if window == window2 and (event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Save & Close')):
            window2.close()
            window2 = None
            window1.un_hide()
    window1.close()

#Running the program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If the second window is not called it works as intended but i cannot think of why calling the second window would cause the KeyError, i dont see the connection.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ps2ee\Downloads\Testmulti.py", line 59, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\ps2ee\Downloads\Testmulti.py", line 36, in main
    if values['IN'] != '':
KeyError: 'IN'
```

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error is.  Please update the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: Before you use the key to index the value from `values`, make sure which `window` it returned from function `sg.read_all_windows()`. The dictionary `values` is about the element values for `window`. There will no any Input element with key `'IN'` if the `window` is `window1`.

Comment: @JasonYang, Thank you i didn't realize!

Answer (score 0):

i was able to get it to work with the following.

```
 if window == window1 and values['IN'] != '':                         
        search = values['IN']
        # do the filtering
        new_values = [x for x in pt_list if search in x]
        # display in the listbox
        window1['LIST'].update(new_values)     
    else:
    # display original unfiltered list
        window1['LIST'].update(pt_list)
    # if a list item is chosen, switch to patient folder
    if event == 'LIST' and len(values['LIST']):
        window2 = make_window2()
        window1.hide()
```

I wasn't checking for which window object values["IN"] was in. thank you @JasonYang for pointing me in the right direction